# How can I implement google sign in method only with institutional mail (xx.ac.in) in android with java?

Tags: java, google-signin, credentials

I am developing a app for my university in which I want the control over the sign in method.
The user with the institutional mail can log in.

Currently I am using this method

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    Log.wtf("User", user.getDisplayName());
                    if (user.getEmail().endsWith("xx.ac")) {
                        finish();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        mAuth.signOut();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login With Institutional Mail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

```
                }
```